# Creating custom resources and change fallback logic

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, multilingual

I have a multilingual application. The strings are extracted to resource-files. For example there are two resource-files:

```
Resources.resx     (for english)
Resources.de.resx  (for german)
```

Now, I have a (german-)customer who want to replace some german translations with it's own words.

My Idea was now, to create a additional Resource-File for example `Resources.custom.resx`. On the end, the application should the resources from `Resources.custom.resx` and if it not exists there, from `Resources.de.resx` and as last fallback from `Resources.resx`.

Is this a possible way to reach my goal? Can someone help me, how I can realize this? Perhaps, there are samples which I can use?

Comment: Yes why not just check the directory to see whether `Resources.xyz.resx` exist or not and take decision accordingly?